# How do I make my if condition work within a thread in Java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, java-threads

I want to print a string only if it equals to a particular string e.g. "Hello", but when I run the program in a new thread, although it exe cutes the whole code, it does not print the string "Hello" even when the condition is true. I am attaching the code below :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doGetRequest();
                }
            }).start();




private void doGetRequest() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.connectTimeout(10,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(10,TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        String url = "my_url";

        client = builder.build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();


        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String jsonData = response.body().string();
            JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("Flights");
             for(int i = 0; i<jarray.length();i++){
                 JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                 Log.v("objectttt", String.valueOf(object));
                 String adft= object.getString("Adft");
                 if(adft=="Hello") {

                      Log.v("hereee", adft);
                 } else {
                     Log.v("hereee", adft);
                      //it prints Hello here
                 }
             }
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use == for Strings; they are reference types.  Use adft.equals("Hello") instead, and see if that works.

Comment: Are you seeing the result of Log.v("objectttt", String.valueOf(object))? If not, change to Log.e(), you may have set your logger to a different level.

Comment: You can also use adft.contentEquals("Hello") to check